# Netty handler, should we write super.channelRead() when overrides, what's its job?

Tags: netty, handler

```
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
    super.channelRead(ctx, msg);
    //write our own code here
｝
```

Whether should we write super.channelRead? And why?

Comment: Which class is your handler extending?

Answer (score 1):

```
Whether should we write super.channelRead?
```

That depends. The default behavior of `channelRead` in [ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.html#channelRead(io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext,%20java.lang.Object)) is forward the msg to the next `ChannelInboundHandler`. If there is no other handlers care about the `msg`, then there is no need to call it.